in dexiedb after i restart application and open DB, created tables are gone ( sort of ?)
Im writing a program that will let users convert their tiled game scenes ( json ) to a dexiedb database.  The intention is to convert the json files at the beginning of the game. once converted the game files don't need to be converted again.
however i am having trouble utilizing dexieDB, when i restart my application and reopen my database, its as if my created table(s) is sort of missing? I can no longer reference my tables using db.tableName format. I can however see the tables I previously created in the storeNames and _alltables properties in the db object.
here is how my class is utilized by client:
const spatialdb = new SpatialDB() // create dexieDB instance
await spatialdb.init() // init the database
await spatialdb.convertMap(filepath) // converts the json if needed

and here is a sample code of my library:
the way it works is at the beginning i create a table called converted_maps
to store the names of any jsons that have been successfully converted.
export default class SpatialDB {
  static instance;
  constructor() { // create a singleton
    if (!SpatialDB.instance) {
      SpatialDB.instance = this;
      this.db = new Dexie(DB_NAME);
    }
    return SpatialDB.instance;
  }
  async init() {
    //create initial schema for database
    if (this.db.verno < 1) {
      const databaseExists = await Dexie.exists(DB_NAME);
      if (!databaseExists) {
        await this.db.version(1).stores({ converted_maps: "map_name" });
      } else {
        await this.db.open();
        debugger;
      }
    }
  }
  async convertMap(path) {
    const mapName = this._getPathFileName(path);

    const isConverted = await this.db.converted_maps
      .where("map_name")
      .equals(mapName)
      .toArray();
    debugger;

    const needToConvert = Array.isArray(isConverted) && isConverted.length == 0;

    if (needToConvert) {
      // convert the map then once done add this map to table of converted maps
      // await this._convertTiledToMap(path);
      await this.db.converted_maps.add({ map_name: mapName });
      debugger;
    }
  }
  /**
   *
   * @param {string} path
   * @return returns the filename of the json based on the path given
   */
  _getPathFileName(path) {
    const parts = path.split("/");
    const tableName = parts[parts.length - 1].replace(".json", "");
    return tableName;
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param {*} mapName
   * @param {*} schema
   * @description creates a new schema in the database for the given map
   */
  async _addSchema(mapName, schema) {
    const currentVersion = this.db.verno;
    if (currentVersion >= 1) {
      // Close the database before modifying the schema
      try {
        if (this.db.isOpen()) {
          await this.db.close();
        }
      } catch (e) {
        debugger;
      }

      // Collect existing tables
      const existingSchema = await this.db.tables.reduce((acc, table) => {
        acc[table.name] = table.schema.primKey.src;
        return acc;
      }, {});
      debugger;
      // Add the new table schema
      existingSchema[mapName] = schema;

      // Increment the version and update schema
      await this.db.version(currentVersion + 1).stores(existingSchema);
      debugger;
      // Re-open the database
      await this.db.open();
      debugger;
    }
  }

but after relaunching the table goes sort of missing:


Use a declarative schema no matter if database exists or not:
https://dexie.org/docs/Tutorial/Understanding-the-basics
